# How can I change permissions on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: ubuntu, file-permissions

I've installed Ubuntu Server and Ubuntu Desktop 12.04.3 LTS, and have installed [Froxlor server management panel](http://www.froxlor.org/). At the end of the Froxlor installation, it created a file `userdata.inc.php` in the `/tmp` folder.

Now I have to move that to the `/lib` folder, but I can't. I can't edit it, copy it, view it or move it because it says I don't have permission.

I've tried everything, even opening Filezilla and trying to FTP the file to another host to transfer back to the right folder. It just keeps saying I don't have permission.

What are these permissions, and how can I get them?

Comment: As has been hinted to in the comments to [Fiasco Labs' answer](http://superuser.com/a/639772/53590): *why would you need to put a PHP source code file in /lib?* /lib is for binary library files, not web application source code or configuration. My guess would be that you are looking for somewhere under /var/www or /srv instead, or /etc at "worst".

Answer (score 5):

This is one of those questions that is kind of multi-level. Some of them are basic Linux Operator 101 issues that you need to familarize yourself with in order to manage this system.

**First Issue** is that you must understand permissions as they apply in the Linux file system.

There are five pertinent attributes that are applicable to both files and directories.

- The first is the owner of the item
- The second is the group ownership of the item
- The third is the kind of access the owner has to the file/directory
- The fourth is the kind of access the group has to the file/directory
- The fifth is the kind of access allowed for everyone else to the file/directory

You can see them when you list the files using `ls -l`

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 bondobob apache2  4096 Apr 13  2011 public_ftp/
```

**Next issue** is that in order to move a file, you will need to either own the file, belong to a group that has necessary rights or be the root user. You will also need applicable rights and ownership on the directory you are moving the file to.

Usually on modern linux systems, it is not allowed to log in as root, so you must use a command called `sudo` (super user do) to escalate your system access to root level.

`sudo mv somefile /path/to/somefile` will prompt you for your password and if your login name is listed in `/etc/sudoers`, you will be prompted for your password and the command will be executed.

**Final Issue** is that moving the file may not be enough for what you really want to accomplish as the permissions issue is due to the fact you're trying to transfer a file from somewhere in system `/tmp` to somewhere in `/lib` and probably will need to use the `chown` command to set proper **owner** and **group** and use `chmod` to set **owner/group/global read/write/execute** permissions on the file so the system can access it properly. Once again, `sudo` will be needed to escalate your privileges to use these commands.

Files contained in the `/lib` directory will probably be owned by **root.root** and have **rw-r--r--** (read/write by owner, read only for everyone else) permissions. In order to edit, you will have to use `sudo` for privilege escalation to load the file in your editor of choice. It's a bad idea to have these files editable by anyone other that either the root user or the daemon user.

This is kind of ending up in tldr; territory so if there are specific followup questions...

Comment: Tho, I'd add using 'sudo' is generally the ubuntu way, and su would not work in a traditional ubuntu setup, since root has no password. To get the equivilent of su, you need to use sudo su

Comment: Grrr... Meant SUDO, will edit. At least I got sudoers right... drrr...

Comment: Its a pretty natural error to make - hell, my vps uses sudo, rather than sudoers. I'm guessing I'm missing something in this question - why would a PHP script need to be moved, manually to /lib?

Comment: I'd have to care about Froxlor enough to go dig that up. Sounds like a make file with a misplaced sense of direction, or the package creator oopsed.

Comment: Yeah, or there's a misunderstanding somewhere. Its probably why no one answered it earlier, and this question was closed, much to the annoyance of the OP.

Comment: Don't you need `w` on the parent dir to move a file, similar to deletion? Also, in the case of `/tmp`, it involves the sticky bit, where that's also not enough.